# Is there a list of the potential close reasons that < 3000 rep users can see?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “closed” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question)

Just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might not be exactly what you're looking for, in the sense that it's not necessarily accurate for every SE site, but if you're wondering about Stack Overflow/Server Fault/Super User, there's a screen capture of the close window on the [Privileges Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) page.

Edit: There's also a list of reasons in [this FAQ answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question/10583#10583).  Which kind of makes this a dupe...