# List of close reasons for Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange-2.0, close-reasons

Originally I asked [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68762/is-there-a-list-of-the-potential-close-reasons-that-3000-rep-users-can-see-cl) which got closed because there is an [FAQ question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question/10583#10583) that lists the close reasons for the SO trilogy sites.  But then I saw [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15381/best-computer-internet-based-practical-joke-closed) on Programmers that was closed for being "Not Constructive".  This close reason is not listed on the aforementioned FAQ question, so I'm assuming that this is specific to Programmers.
If each SE site can have a different set of close reasons, is there a place where "< 3000 rep" users can see the Close Reasons for a particular SE site?

Answer (score 5):

You make a good point! I don't know whether there is such a place for every close reason. It seems pretty clear to me how to proceed from here, though.

If the close reason is common, then it should be added to [the FAQ entry you linked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question/10583#10583).

If the close reason is only used on one or two sites, then it should be added to the analogous FAQ entry on the relevant per-site meta(s). If no such entry exists, one should be created.